# "Трудно выполнимо": слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Цитата из повести О. Ларионовой "Картель": "Моя флегматичность тебе известна, следовательно, намерение твое трудно выполнимо".
Разве "трудно выполнимо" в данном предложении следует писать раздельно? Интуиция подсказывает мне, что слитно.
Цитату взял не из инета, а из бумажной книги. Лениздат, 1981.
Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***трудновыполнимо.***

Русский орфографический [словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9&mode=slovari&l=1): трудновыполнимый.

**Пояснение**

Возможно сочетание **"вполне выполнимо",** здесь наречие указывает на степень признака.

А вот сочетание **"трудно выполнимо"** противоречиво по своей семантике: если решение трудно выполнить, то можно ли считать его **выполнимым.**

Большой толковый словарь

**ВЫПОЛНИМЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -ним, -а, -о. Такой, который можно выполнить; осуществимый. В-ое задание. Эта задача **вполне выполнима.** Выполнимость, -и; ж.

Comment: Спасибо, именно таким образом я и размышлял, но решил подстраховаться, спросив у знатоков.

Comment: Странно, что такая довольно нелепая ошибка нашлась в бумажной книге, изданной в советские времена. Что ж, всякое бывает.

Comment: @Spheinx, никакая это в книге не ошибка. Как не ошибкой было бы и слитное написание… Оба варианта правильны.